# Toggling Chrome Pages on Mac

Tags: macos, toggle

On Windows, each browser page was a separate application. This made it **very easy** to flexibly toggle between a specific pair of Chrome browser pages with Ctrl (Cmd) + Tab. I was wondering if there was a way to set this up on Mac. As of now, `cmd` + ` cycles between ALL pages, which is not what I want.

For example, let's say I have 4 (separate) Chrome pages open: A, B, C, and D. Pages A and B correspond to one task and C and D to another. I want to be able to toggle between pages A and B for a while (Ctrl-Tab). Then, afterwards, without closing pages A and B, I want to Ctrl-Tab between pages C and D for a while. Windows made this process very easy: I'd just have to access the two pages I want to toggle between once, and ctrl-tab simply allowed switching between the two pages since each page was a separate application.

Is there a way I can do or set up a way to do this on Mac?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a feature which could set the behavior you described above, the **Command + Tab**, **Command and press Shift+ Tab** and **Command + `** are the only shortcut currently available for this kind of tasks. I have searched in the apple support also but I was not able to find anything that may help

cheers